# Sails hook controllers bad register

Tags: hook, mootools, sails.js, controllers

Im using mootools server side with sails. This let me create classes that can be extended and much more features, but the problem comes when sails hook controllers try to register the controller actions. They use ._each and the mootools object has properties like $constructor And sails try to register this as action and then the error....How can override this with the mootools each method? The mootools each method skip this properties and then all should works ok

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

yeah, this is a problem with sails. `_.each` is meant to be used for iterating Objects but it will work on Arrays because they are really Objects with Array-like properties. It should get changed to `_.forEach`.

In the meanwhile, since you are in nodejs, you can configure the Array prototype to hide the enumerables like this:

```
var foo = ['one','two'],
    key;

for (key in foo){
    // lists all mootools methods and properties as well as 0, 1
    console.log(key, foo[key]); // needs hasOwnProperty etc, ppl complain.
}

// protect enumerables under ES5 in Array
(function(){
    // set mootools expandos to non-enumerables under ES5
    var key,
        a = [];

    for (key in a) a.hasOwnProperty(key) || Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, key, {
        enumerable:false
    });
}());

console.info('trying again...');

for (key in foo){
    console.log(key, foo[key]);    
}
```

I wrote about it a while ago - http://fragged.org/hiding-enumerables-after-mootools-changes-prototypes_1552.html

there is an issue for mootools-core 1.6 - https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/issues/2665 - which should be done soon-ish.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the quick reply.

How can i do this without touch the sailsjs lib hook? Can i patch mootools for this? Sorry but im not expert on mootools and i don't know where do this change. I read in your post that i can do something like this:

    if (previous == null || !previous.$protected) this.prototype[name] = method;
    Object.defineProperty && Object.defineProperty(this, name, { enumerable: false });

But, where?

Thanks!

Comment: ah you use MooTools Classes? yeah they have a few 'hidden' properties that will cause a problem. You can easily fix that.. will post later

Comment: the problem is here in sails: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/controllers/index.js#L90-L108 - the implication is they expect a PJSO and they get a MooTools class which will have $caller, $parent, $constructor etc, some of which will cause issues. they should be using `_.forIn()` here, or even https://lodash.com/docs#forOwn as they claim unwanted props can be hidden on the prototypes. I still have commit access to Sails, may send a PR if you can create a usecase - post a small controller you mixin and what you get exactly.

Comment: Sorry Dimitar, what is a PR? How can i send you the controller and the error in the hook?

Comment: In lodash, _.each and _.forEach are aliases of each other: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js#L11225.

Comment: @FernandoRubio a PR is a Pull Request on Github to add new code to the repository.